# Creating linked list parsing line trouble

Tags: java, parsing

I am reading lines from a file, the total number is around 150,000 lines. Each time a line is read

-i modify the object city,

-then add it to the linked list

-then print out the content of the linked list in the last position, and I find it correct.

-after the filereader loop ends, i find that all the object on the linkedlist have the same city value, which is the last value entered ( last line of the file read) --> this is the problem

```
public static void lala() throws IOException{

    String FileLine;



    BufferedReader R = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "list_of_1000_cities with coords.txt"));


    city x = new city() ;


    while ((FileLine = R.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] Tokens = FileLine.split(",");


        if (Preprocessor.get_double(Tokens[1])!=0 && Preprocessor.get_double(Tokens[2])!=0) {



        x.latitude= Double.parseDouble(Tokens[1]);


        x.longitude= Double.parseDouble(Tokens[2]);

        x.name= Tokens[0];
        citylist.add(x );

        System.out.println(citylist.get(citylist.size() - 1).name);
         //prints the correct name

        }
    }

        System.out.println(citylist.get(1115).name);

    // always prints the last name on the file read no matter how much i change the index printed 

}
```

Comment: Why are you always printing out an element at index 1115? Also, you shouldn't access elements of a LinkedList by index for performance reasons - every time you do it the list starts counting from its head until it reaches the required index.

Comment: I'm not always printing it, it's out of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java refers to objects by references. Hence within your while loop you are modifying the value of the same reference to X that you have assigned outside the loop.

Instantiate a new value of X within the while loop for each of the co-ordinates and then add it to the list - your problem will be solved.

To be more specific with your code :

String FileLine;

```
BufferedReader R = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
        "list_of_1000_cities with coords.txt"));





while ((FileLine = R.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] Tokens = FileLine.split(",");


    if (Preprocessor.get_double(Tokens[1])!=0 && Preprocessor.get_double(Tokens[2])!=0) {

    city x = new city() ;

    x.latitude= Double.parseDouble(Tokens[1]);


    x.longitude= Double.parseDouble(Tokens[2]);

    x.name= Tokens[0];
    citylist.add(x );

    System.out.println(citylist.get(citylist.size() - 1).name);
     //prints the correct name

    }
}

    System.out.println(citylist.get(1115).name);
```